# Using Github's GraphQL to list all tags and search for releases

Tags: c#, git, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to use GraphQL to get all tags from a repository and later (or if possible, in the same command) get some details of the release of each tag.

I'm trying to do this approach `git/refs/tags` -> `releases/tags/[tag_name]` because listing all releases by `releases` is not giving me the whole list of releases.

In v3, this is the equivalent to this:

`"https://api.github.com/repos/" + repo + "/git/refs/tags"`
`"https://api.github.com/repos/" + repo + "/releases/tags/" + tag`

In the [GraphQL Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/), I was able to construct this query (replace with your own username and repo):

```
{
  repository(owner: ":UserName", name: ":Repository") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", last: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it's giving this result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "refs": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "2.1"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "2.2"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "2.3"
            }
          },
 [...]
```

---

I somehow need to fit this into the query too (just an example, I need other fields too), taking the `name` and using as parameter:

```
repository(owner: ":UserName", name: ":Repository") {
  release(tagName: name) {
    name
  }
}
```

Trying like this:

```
query ListTags {
  repository(owner: ":Username", name: ":Repository") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", last: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          repository {
            release(tagName: Ref.name) {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm unable to use `Ref.name` as the parameter to `release`.

---

When using the query in my project, the object returned has all the JSON nodes, not actually simply the `name` field.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/graphql")
};

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "ReleaseSearcher");

var basicValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"username:key"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basicValue);

var queryObject = new
{
    query = @"query {
        repository(owner: "":Username"", name: "":repo"") {
            refs(refPrefix: ""refs/tags/"", last: 100) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }",
    variables = new { }
};

var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryObject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};

dynamic responseObj;

using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString);
}

Console.WriteLine(responseObj.data.viewer.login);
Console.ReadLine();
```

---

**How can I search for individual releases using the tag name?**

**How can I properly read the result data?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get what I want with this:

```
query {
    rateLimit {
        cost
        remaining
     }
     repository(owner: "NickeManarin", name: "ScreenToGif") {
         refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", last: 100) {
             nodes {
                 repository {
                     releases(last: 100, orderBy: { field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
                         nodes {
                             name
                             createdAt
                             url
                             releaseAssets(last: 2) {
                                 nodes {
                                     name
                                     downloadCount
                                     downloadUrl
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

I'm just not sure if it's the best way of doing it.

Comment: this worked for me as well.  it should be marked as the correct answer